# How to launch single-file programs in Java 11 (or later)?

Tags: java, java-11

[JEP 330](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330) describes a new feature in JDK 11 for launching single-file programs in Java. I've tried:

`$ ./Example.java`

but it doesn't work. What is the correct usage?

Comment: Sometime back, I wrote an article over [Introduction to Java — Simplified](https://medium.com/@nigamnaman/introduction-to-java-simplified-56c8b887a799) to provide a similar sample and how it works.

Answer (score 6):

#### Short-version:

```
$ java Example.java data.txt
```

or (with `#!`):

```
$ ./example data.txt
```

#### Details:

Working example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/gists/tree/master/java_11_aug_2018/stack_o).

Consider a single-file program to print the lines in a file:

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ExampleJDK11 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // snip ... print file args[0]
    }
}
```

#### Usage 1:

Assuming the code is in `Example.java` and that `java` is on the `PATH`, then usage is:

`java Example.java data.txt`

- Note that there is no `javac` step (!)
- Note that the filename need not match the classname.

#### Usage 2:

Assume the code is in a file, `example`, with a "shebang" line at the top:

```
#!/Users/measter/tools/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java --source 8 

import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
// as above
```

Usage is:

`./example data.txt`

Answer (score 5):

Though the [answer by you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51935637/1746118) includes correct information. Just trying to put this into simpler terms, a file can simply be executed using `java` from JDK11 onwards, for example on MacOS

```
.../jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java Sample.java
```

This would seek and execute the standard ***`public static void main(String[] args)`*** method. As one can notice(even beginners) that this method accepts `args` of type `String`, hence the arguments placed after the *name of the source file* in the original command line are passed to the compiled class when it is executed. Therefore the following command

```
.../jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java <file-name>.java arg1 arg2
```

would provide the string arguments `arg1`, `arg2` during the execution phase.

***Side note*** - If the file includes multiple classes with standard main methods, the first top-level class found in the source file which shall contain the declaration of the standard *public static void main(String[])* method is executed.