# Running a Java program without compiling

Tags: java

Recently, I installed Java 11. When coding, accidentally, instead of compiling `Main.java` with `javac Main.java`, I wrote `java Main.java`. It did not show me any errors and worked out without any issues. Why did this happen? Is this a new feature in newer versions of Java?

Contents of `Main.java`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

Running in Java 8:

```
java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b16, mixed mode)

>>> java Main.java
Error: Could not find or load main class Main.java
```

Running in Java 11:

```
java version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode)

>>> java Main.java
Hello, World!
```

Comment: Yes, Java 11 introduced the ability to execute single-file programs using the source file. Check this: [How to launch single-file programs in Java 11 (or later)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51935636/how-to-launch-single-file-programs-in-java-11-or-later)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This feature was introduced as a part of JEP 330: Launch Single-File Source-Code Programs.

> In source-file mode, the effect is as if the source file is compiled
>   into memory, and the first class found in the source file is executed.
>   For example, if a file called HelloWorld.java contains a class called
>   hello.World, then the command
>
> java HelloWorld.java is informally equivalent to
>
> javac -d  HelloWorld.java java -cp  hello.World

This is the [JEP](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330)