# What is the difference between running a java file with or without .java extension of a file

Tags: java

I popped into the terminal and ran a hello world script using the following command `java Hello`, and it ran like normal java programs. I proceeded to run `java Hello.java`, and then Java took a while (1.0 seconds).

Why does using the second command, `java Hello.java`, take longer to execute than using `java Hello.`

Comment: You can't execute `.java` files. Those files need to be compiled first. I'm surprised `java Hello.java` even ran without manually compiling this file beforehand.

Comment: It doesn't. That's not a valid performance test.

Comment: @tkausl as of Java 11, you can compile and run Java files like this. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54493058/running-a-java-program-without-compiling/54493093

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a Java program without compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54493058/running-a-java-program-without-compiling)

Answer (score 5):

> Why does using the second command, `java Hello.java`, take longer to execute than using `java Hello`.

`java Hello.java` only works in [Java 11+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54493058/running-a-java-program-without-compiling/54493093): it is compiling `Hello.java`, then running it.

`java Hello` isn't compiling anything. It's just running something that was previously compiled. This is quicker because it's doing less: it's not compiling, just running.

Answer (score 0):

Before JAVA 11, the procedure to execute Java files through command line was:

First compile the java file.

```
javac nameOfFile.java
```

The above command creates a nameOfFile.class file.
You will see the file if run either `ls` or `dir` depending on your OS.
When you run

```
java nameOfFile
```

It interpretes the nameOfFile.class file and gives you output.

From JAVA 11, you get the option to launch a single source code file directly, without intermediate compilation.
Hope this answers your question