# How to determine a java program output without any IDE?

Tags: java, loops, output

I want to know that is there a way to determine a output of any java program without any dedicated IDE? For an example, a program snippet may be like...

```
int i=3,n=0;
while (i<4)
{
   n++;
   i--;
}
System.out.println(n);
```

Comment: Is here someone to answer my question?

Comment: I want to determine a correct output

Comment: ...Like the one i added with the question...

Comment: There is no "correct output" in your question. I downvoted  because 
[No research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/)

Comment: I also know i can write a java program without an IDE... i have a basic knowledge

Comment: It depends on your OS (shells, environment variables).  Your question seems basic so forgive posters if they ask for missing basic info.  Like what attempts have you made?

Comment: Will the program prints the value of n?

Comment: Related: [How to launch single-file programs in Java 11 (or later)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51935636/how-to-launch-single-file-programs-in-java-11-or-later)

Comment: With a small fragment of code like the one in the question, can you step through it line-by-line in your head, and understand what each line is doing? If not, then you can research the specific statement/syntax which is causing a problem. If you want to confirm your understanding by executing the code in as simple a way as possible, then you now have several suggestions, here. (There are also online tools which can execute your Java code.) But learning to use an IDE will be a good investment (assuming you don't already use one).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute a java .class from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279542/how-to-execute-a-java-class-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Java version 9 or higher, you can use the Java REPL (JShell) to try pieces of code. Install it on your computer, or use an online service (e.g. replit.com).

Or, use a text editor, and create a .java file, compile it and run it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html

Answer (score 0):

If you got JDK9+ you can run your java code on prompt with no ide. try run `jshell` on prompt/cmd/powershell and test your code. if you need run a lot of line on jshell try `/edit`