# Error: Main class Test could not be found or loaded

Tags: java

I created an easy script with notepad++ and run in the cmd with this command:

```
java -cp . Test
```

Result:

```
Error: Main class Test could not be found or loaded
```

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "npcData.csv";
        String line = "";
        String csvSplitBy = ";";
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] npc = line.split(csvSplitBy);
                System.out.println("nonCritSpecialNpc['" + npc[0] + "'] = true;");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Fehler beim Lesen der Datei: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

What am I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things you're missing here.

First, for public classes, the name of the class should match the name of the file. I.e., you either need to rename your class to `Test`, or rename the file to `Main.java`.

Second, you're missing a crucial step here - compiling. Java is not an interpreted language. You need to convert your `.java` class to something the JVM can run. This is done using the Java Compiler, or `javac` for short:

```bash
javac Main.java
```

After doing that, you'll have a `.class` file that the JVM can execute:

```bash
java -cp . Main
```

Comment: I tested this too before i posted the question, i get the same error :/

Comment: @Kababum did you compile the code?

Comment: i just writed in notepad++ named it Test.java and running in cmd, i think now this is wrong, because you asked me that :D

Comment: @Kababum OK, now I see the issue - you're missing at least one key step here. See my edited answer.

Comment: Also worth noting that in Java 11 and later, you can run simple (single-file) Java programs without an explicit compile step. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51935636/how-to-launch-single-file-programs-in-java-11-or-later).