Running Java file in Gitlab CI/CD
I have a .java file in my repository and I have decided to execute it in my pipeline because it will generate a file that will be used in the rest of the script.
To do so, I have done the following :
script:
 - javac "myFile.java"
 - java myFile

However, I am getting the following error :
Error: Could not find or load main class myFile
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myFile

I was wondering if it was even do-able as I only found documentation on executing .sh files. So what is the reason to my error and if it's not possible to do, how can I overcome this ?

Is your class named myFile? Does myFile.java have a package statement?

My class is indeed named myFile and myFile.java doesn't have a package statement.

Note that you may be able to directly run the .java file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51935636/how-to-launch-single-file-programs-in-java-11-or-later
